# Chromecast not responding to my AppID on Chrome, but on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast

I have whitelisted my Chromecast. I checked the send serial to google button. I rebooted it. I can open DevTools. I used the sample code on GitHub. Android sample works perfectly, by just changing the AppID in strings.xml. I can connect, cast to my chromecast, see my reciever page debug on DevTools. However, when I used Chrome, It did not work. I followed the tutorial and constructed my app. When the AppID is YouTube the response client list is recieved with my chromecast. (I see its IP address) However when I just change the AppID to my given AppId, it does not work. The empty client list is returned from the Cast API. If it did not work on Android, I would follow the other instructions (which I already have done), reboot, select send device id checkbox etc. But I am just confused, what can be wrong? I am using Windows 8.1 with Chrome 31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperantly doing nothing and waiting for 20 more minutes after this post has worked. Strange.